# Radiator valve part help

Tags: valve, radiator

I recently tried to turn the valve to open it a bit more after noticing the top of my bedroom radiator was not as hot as the rest of the home.

I noticed while turning, a part cracked and came off, it was rusted away.

I don't know what it does and if it's bad to leave it as is.

My googling failed me, my assumption from the look of it, it's some type of stopper to prevent opening/closing too much?

I've attached a picture of similar from another rooms radiator valve.[image]

Thank you.

Comment: IDK the answer to your question but if the *top* of your radiator is cold, if there's a somewhat sharp line part way up the radiator where it's hot below and cold above, you need to bleed your radiator.  That means releasing air that has collected inside it.  The valve is not the issue.   Bleeding a radiator is easy, just look it up on youtube.

Comment: Thanks, the top is almost hot. Thought if I open the valve a little more it would help it get hot

Comment: It is possible that this radiator valve is partly closed, the radiator is getting less flow than others, and will heat up more slowly than others.  Depending on many factors the radiator may never fully heat up.   Opening the valve more may or may not help.  These kinds of problems are hard to diagnose.   It is possible there's air in the radiator .... that is very very easy to diagnose. I would do that first, just to fix it or rule it out.

Comment: @jay613 thanks, will give it a try. I wasn't sure because I was reading bleed when it's cold but it's warm where I could keep my hand on it while others I would need to pull off

Comment: A bit of cautious bleeding never hurts, and is worth considering as a standard part of bringing up a hydronic heating system for the winter. Might as well make sure you're running at the best efficiency you can get.